# React Native With Expo Button name is clipping

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have created a new react native app using expo but when I button the component its text gets clipped as you can see image below the Add and Cancel button names are clipping.

[image]

Comment: please upload the code (especially render portion)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the issue was with the width by default it is not taking the button text width. So solve this issue by adding the View component as a parent and added width [image]